# Unable to import css files into NextJs project

Tags: javascript, next.js

Currently I have my index.js file that has my display components. For CSS I have downloaded a css file from an [external source](https://bootswatch.com/). I am then adding the .css file into my styles folder that comes when you make the initial `npx create-next-app`. This file I'm then trying to import into my index.js file like so: `import bootStyles from "../styles/bootstrap.css"`. But doing this gives me this error:

> error - ./styles/bootstrap.css Global CSS cannot be imported from
> files other than your Custom . Please move all global CSS imports
> to pages_app.js. Or convert  the import to Component-Level CSS (CSS
> Modules). Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/css-global
> Location: pages\index.js

Additionally I have also tried using the Head component like so:

```
import Head from 'next/head'

<Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/bootstrap.css"/>
</Head>
```

This doesnt show an error but the styles still dont reflect on my webpage.

Comment: As the error suggests, try moving your global CSS import to `_app`: `import "../styles/bootstrap.css"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either put all your CSS imports in `_app.tsx` or you can add `*.module.css` to your filenames so they get picked up.

You can also override the nextjs webpack config:

```
// next.config.js

module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, webpack }) => {
    return config
  },
}

...

{
  test: /\.s?[ac]ss$/,
  use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
  exclude: [/node_modules/],
},
```

In order to override the module rules and css loader, however I wouldn't recommend this if you don't know what you're doing.